# Angular Material Date Picker Set Only a Particular Day of Week Selectable (Eg: Monday)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-material, days

I wonder is there any filtering mechanism for the Angular Material Date Picker, So that I can set only Mondays are selectable from the Date Picker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. There is an attribut called `md-date-filter` which you can use to specify the day you want to be selected by user. In the below example as you are returing  `return day === 1;` It will allow to select mondays only. you can change it from o to 7 as required.

html view file

```
<md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date" md-date-filter="onlyMonday">
</md-datepicker>
```

In Controller File

```
$scope.onlyMonday = function(date) {
                          var day = date.getDay();
                          return day === 1;
}
```

http://codepen.io/next1/pen/EKmdPx

Comment: Thank You Very Much !!! :-) Another thing I couldn't figure out, is there any possibility to set next closest Monday with respect to the current date ??

Ex: Say Today is 25th March 2016... So that I want to set 28th March 2016 Which is the Closest Monday to the current date...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](http://codepen.io/webservconsultant/pen/wGOEoy). It defaults to next monday on datepicker.

```
$scope.today = new Date('05/30/2016');
$scope.nextMonday = $scope.today;
daystoAdd = 7 - ($scope.today.getDay()) + 1;
$scope.nextMonday.setDate($scope.today.getDate() + daystoAdd);
```