# Angular datetime picker with specified date/time range

Tags: angular, datetimepicker

I'm currently building a application for a screen-repair service i'm organizing at my university. With the online tool users can schedule an appointment to get their device repaired.

For the schedule process i'm looking for a Angular date-timepicker component that can accept the following options:

- Users should be able to pick weekdays only
- Should be only allowed to pick times between 9:00 - 16:00. Each repair should take about 30 minutes, so appointments should only be made on XX:30 / XX:00 and should always last 30 minutes.
- If possible asynchronously get current appointments from firebase and disable those XX:30 timespans in the UI

I've been looking around for datetime-pickers, but wasn't able to find any that could follow the first 2 criteria. Therefor i'm asking here if anyone has been working with one that accepts (at least the first 2 criteria) these options.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you had a look at Angular Material datepicker? https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview

Answer (score 0):

You can use npm package manager It gives plenty of options to disable dates on weekends and so on :

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-pick-datetime
```

Comment: Seems about good for the first 2 criteria. I'll give it a try now shortly

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Angular Material datepicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview).

To implement the requirements from the points 1 and 2 please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36199119/3018671).

Comment: The material datepicker still doesn't support to pick time as far as i see from the documentation